# How can I sort dates based on day and month but not year?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how could I group some birthdays based on the day and month. I am trying to retrieve the users based on their birthdays. What I have done is as below

```
$blogusers = get_users(array(
    'role'      => 'member',
    'meta_key'  => 'birth_date',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
));

foreach($blogusers as $user){
$name = $user->display_name;
$date = $user->birth_date;
$profile_photo = $user->profile_photo;
$date = date("M d",strtotime($date));

echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$date.'</td></tr>';

}
```

Expected result is

```
Dec 12
Dec 10
Nov 05
```

What I am getting is

```
Dec 10
Nov 05
Dec 12
```

Any suggestions to make it work would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

By default Wordpress's meta value sorting is done alphabetically, you will need to define type of value you are sorting.

```php
$blogusers = get_users(array(
    'role'      => 'member',
    'meta_key'  => 'birth_date',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_date',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
));
```

It is briefly mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not working.  Let's assume the birthdates are 12-Dec-1990, 10-Dec-1980, 05-Nov-1985. It's still sorting based on years, not days and months. Can we modify the array result in PHP anyhow?